# Random background gifs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, background

I have code that when the body loads, it chooses a random gif from a folder and uses that as the background.  When a new page loads, or the same page, it chooses another random gif as the background.  I've looked online, and even though the code is relatively the same, it doesn't load the new gif as the background.  Here's the HTML code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Random Background Image -->
    <script>
    function newBackground()
    {
        // Set up the image files to be used.
        var theBackgrounds = new Array() // do not change this

        // To add more image files, continue with the pattern below, adding to the array.
        theBackgrounds[0] = 'images/EXTRA/Backgrounds/equalizer.gif'
        theBackgrounds[1] = 'images/EXTRA/Backgrounds/equalizer2.gif'
        theBackgrounds[2] = 'images/EXTRA/Backgrounds/recordSpinning.gif'

        var p = theBackgrounds.length;

        var whichBackground = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));


        document.body.style.background = theBackgrounds[whichBackground];
    }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onLoad="newBackground();">
      *some code*
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the body's CSS code that's in styles.css.

```
body{
        background-size:cover;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-color:#000000;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:13px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align:left;
    }
```

Why is the code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because that is not how you set a background image with CSS. You are missing the url() portion.

It should be

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + theBackgrounds[whichBackground] + ")";
```

Comment: Really?  That was the code they used.  But I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!